# laravel multi-language switch and change locale on load

Tags: laravel, localization, multilingual

I've implemented the language switch functionality following [this post](https://dev.to/fadilxcoder/adding-multi-language-functionality-in-a-website-developed-in-laravel-4ech) and it works perfectly but just when you click on the language switch, though I would like to change the `locale` and store it in the App when the page is loaded.

My function it's a bit different from the one in the post, I've added an `else if` just to make sure that the locale it's in the accepted languages

`App/Middleware/Localization.php`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $availableLangs  = array('en', 'hu', 'pt', 'ro', 'sv');
    $userLangs = substr($request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), 0, 2);

    if (\Session::has('locale'))
    {
        \App::setlocale(\Session::get('locale'));
    }
    else if (in_array($userLangs, $availableLangs))
    {
        \App::setLocale($userLangs);
      // Session::push('locale', $userLangs);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

How can I reuse this function or create a new function to achieve the same result but when you load the website?

I have a lot of route so I think that I will need a function in order to don't repeat the same code over and over.

I don't use the `locale` on the URL and I don't want to use it, so please don't propose a solution that includes that option.

Example of my URLS (each URL can be view with all the available languages)

```
domain/city1/
domain/city1/dashboard/
domain/city2/
domain/city2/dashboard/
domain/admin/
```

I don't want:

```
domain/city1/en/...
domain/city1/pt/...
```

Comment: I think you need to add one more else condition in your code. Whenver the page load by default are you sending this 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' value ? I think you wont get any value when the page load by default so your else if condition to validate the value with accepted languages failed. I would suggest you to add one else condition in that you just default language to session and set it as locale

Comment: I'll give it a try, I'm new to Laravel so there are a lot of things I don't understand. is this code suppose to work also on load or just when it receive the URL `locale/{locale}` as it say in the guide?

Comment: Yes this code will work, its not required to pass the locale always in the url. We can do it in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need something like this, whenever the page load initially there won't be any server value so it cannot set value for the `$userLangs` variable. So as per your code, the if statement fails since there is no session value and the elseif condition also fails since there is no value set for `$userLangs` which cannot be found in the $availableLangs. Just add one else condition to set a default lanuage of the website when there is no prefered user language.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) 
{
    $availableLangs  = array('en', 'hu', 'pt', 'ro', 'sv');
    $userLangs = substr($request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), 0, 2);

    if (\Session::has('locale'))
    {
        \App::setlocale(\Session::get('locale'));
    }
    else if (in_array($userLangs, $availableLangs))
    {
        \App::setLocale($userLangs);
        Session::put('locale', $userLangs);
    }
    else {
        \App::setLocale('en');
        Session::put('locale', 'en');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: seems to works now, I've done the same as your code but it say `strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` and it comes from the `if` because if I comment out that it works. is `\Session::get('locale')` an array?

Comment: I think the problem is we have used session::push which i never looked before. Update the code like this `session::put`. I will update my answer now. You need to flush the session once since the value in the session are already stored as array

Comment: Have a look into this link : https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session
Flush the session if required. If the answer is working fine, up vote it ;)

Comment: yes, seems to works though I will need to test it properly with a different computer with a different locale listed in the array to be 100% sure but at least I don't have any error now

Comment: Yes fine, check with different locale values, also i prefer you to have the default locale in .env file instead of hardcoding it in the code. Instead of hardcoding the value 'en' in the code, add it in .env file and access the .env value in the code.

Comment: I have the locale set in the .env but in this way when I go to `domain/city1` my select item with the languages has selected the correct language. I'm using this code `<option value="locale/hu" {{ \Session::get('locale') == 'hu' ? 'selected' : '' }} >HU</option>`